# How to add namespace in a SOAP envelope using axis with Java

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I'm working on a web service project, where I need to alter the default namespace of a soap envelope. I am using axis-1.4.  The following is the generated SOAP envelope.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"             
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  <soapenv:Body> 
      <v1:addClaimRequest xmlns=""> 
        <v1:ClaimsAddRq xsi:type="xsd:string"><ifx:RqUID>004030000075</ifx:RqUID>     
        </v1:ClaimsAddRq> 
     </v1:addClaimRequest> 
  </soapenv:Body>  
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Following is my Java code:

```
    _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
    _call.setSOAPActionURI("v1");
    _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
    _call.setOperationName(new QName("xmlns:v1=urn://shivamath.com/prodschnsmngt/v1/","v1:addClaimRequest"));
    _call.addParameter("v1:ClaimsAddRq",org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_STRING,javax.xml.rpc.ParameterMode.IN);
    _call.setTargetEndpointAddress(locator);
    _call.setEncodingStyle("");
    setRequestHeaders(_call);
    setAttachments(_call);
```

Following is the expected namespace to generate:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:v1="urn://grupoaval.com/prodschnsmngt/v1/"     
  xmlns:ifx="urn://grupoaval.com/xsd/ifx/"> 
  <soapenv:Body> 
    <v1:addClaimRequest xmlns=""> 
      <v1:ClaimsAddRq xsi:type="xsd:string"><ifx:RqUID>004030000075</ifx:RqUID>   
    </v1:ClaimsAddRq> 
  </v1:addClaimRequest> 
 </soapenv:Body>
```

Please guide me out of this problem.

Comment: Hi Prem, you were able to solve this?

Comment: how? could you please explain?

Comment: How? could you please explain?